# Received 'rospack failed to build' message when executed rosmake

Tags: ros, build, rosmake, rospack, makefile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm totally new with ROS and all the robot related stuff, so I'm following all the instructions here to get involved and learn how ROS works.

I'm using Fedora 15 and followed these instructions http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Fedora to install ROS. Everything worked fine, so I continued with the tutorials indicated in this same page to start learning ROS.

Everything was fine until I arrived to the building packages tutorial, I was able to create my first package but when I tried to build it I get the following message:

```
[manu@manu beginner_tutorials]$ rosmake beginner_tutorials
Rospack failed to build
```

I have no idea what can be causing this, I did a search at Google and at the ROS answers page but haven't find yet how to solve this. The most similar error I found related to this pointed to the CDPATH environment variable, but I have already verified that this variable is not set in my machine and also if I set it to '.' get the same result.

I'll really appreciate any suggestion or tip about how to debug this, I know this may be a configuration error or a very elemental question, but I hope that soon I could get more involved with how all this works :D.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29980/received-%27rospack-failed-to-build%27-message-when-executed-rosmake/) by [manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2009/manu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2009/manu/) on 2012-03-27**:
Any suggestions about how to debug this??? I haven't found an answer yet, I'm trying to debug the makefiles to know what can be causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved this... it was a permission issue causing the build to fail.

---

Originally posted by [manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2009/manu/) with karma: 61 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kzr](https://answers.ros.org/users/24034/kzr/) on 2015-12-06**:
how do you solve it? i have the same issue